Intelligent cars that could talk and drive themselves
What is the name of a TV serial or movie that had a group of intelligent cars that could talk and drive themselves? As far as I can remember, the drivers were law-enforcers. They also had a big custom plane they used as temporary base.

Is it Cars 2? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_2

No, it's not an animation.

Those cars had drivers. But they also could also drive themselves. As far as I can remember, the drivers were law-enforcers. They also had a big custom plane they used as temporary base.

Had written a post for Transformers before you added your follow-on comment, but the Autobots didn't have law enforcement drivers, that's for sure.

Yea, it isn't transformers.

@user6028 add the details in question itself.

Could it be Team Knight Rider? 
It was a 90s spin-off of Knight Rider, featuring a team of crime fighters with talking, self-driving cars. They had a transport plane that they used as a mobile base.
